# Draw multiple lines on qmap for a country

Tags: r, ggplot2, qmap

I would like to map multiple connections like [this](http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/), but on a much more precise level (country). To do so, I would like to combine the  qmap package and the packages used in the link, but it doesn't work out. Anyone got som ideas?

I'm already trying this code, but it doesn't work out as well:

```
map = qmap(location='Berlin', zoom = 5)
berlin = c(geom_polygon(aes(long,lat,group=group), size = 0.1, colour= "#090D2A",
                 fill="#090D2A", alpha=0.8, data=map))
```

I get the following error: 
`Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class gg/ggplot`

Anyone got some ideas why? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you are passing an object of type ggplot to the data argument of geom_polygon ("`data=map`"). However, geom_polygon typically expects an object of type data.frame. See `?geom_polygon`.

You could take this example as a starter:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(geosphere)
map <- qmap(location='Berlin', zoom = 5)
n <- 50L
m <- matrix(c(
10,53,20,53,
3,47,23,55),ncol=4,byrow=T)
m <- gcIntermediate(m[,1:2],m[,3:4], n = n)
m <- as.data.frame(cbind(do.call(rbind, m), id=rep(seq_along(m), each = n)))
map + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_path(
    aes(lon,lat,group=id), 
    data=m, 
    arrow = arrow(ends="both"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works! I'm using it now on zoom 13. The line now isn't curve. Do you know how to change the parameters so that the line looks a bit "curved"? And is there a chance to remove the lat and long parameters on the X and Y Axis?

Comment: You can use `geom_curve` with cartesian coordinates: `map + geom_curve(aes(x=lon1,y=lat1,xend=lon2,yend=lat2), data.frame(lon1=13.375,lat1=52.5,lon2=13.425,lat2=52.54)) + coord_cartesian() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)`. Note that the line is(n't) curved for a reason.